# Bootstrap - size panel with wysiwyg editor

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a wysiwyg editor inside a `panel`. I need to change the height of this editor, to say 200px.

How can I accomplish this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <panel heading="Product Description" panel-class="panel-inverse">
             <wysiwyg-edit id="wysiwygProductDescription" content="vm.productDescription" config="vm.productConfig"></wysiwyg-edit>
        </panel>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I tried setting the height of the column with inline style, but the wysiwyg editor just doesn't "fit" inside:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8" style="height: 200px;">
```

I also tried using `-h` and `mh` at the column or row level, but it didn't work.

This is the wysiwyg editor I'm using: https://github.com/psergus/ngWYSIWYG

Comment: wysiwyg-edit .tinyeditor .sizer {
    min-height: unset;
    height: 200px;
}

try this and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wysiwyg-edit .tinyeditor .sizer { 
   min-height: unset; 
   height: 200px; 
}
```